# How to pass a parameter from Azure Automation Runbook to Azure Datafactory pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-automation

I have written below code powershell script to pass the get the value from the logic apps and pass it to Azure data factory.

```
#I am sharing a part of the code which is should pass the parameter to the data factory
# get the clientName value from the logic apps.
Param (
Param (
[Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
[string]
$clientName
)

$parameters = @{
    "clientName" = $clientName
}

#
$Pipeline1 = Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $rg1 -DataFactoryName $adf1 -PipelineName $pn1 -Parameter $parameters
```

But do not know how does my datafactory would get this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a pipeline parameter with the name as same you have used in the declared in automation runbook

```
clientName
```

then use this variable in notebook activities at base parameter area

[image]